# C# User control - Drag and drop and custom propertis

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I have simple user control in VS2017 (picture below)
[User control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0mr2.png)

[image]
Now I wont to use this control in my application using
drag and drop. Not in VS toolbox but in application.
Additionally I want to have properties window like in picture above
in my application. The questions are:

1. How to get properties window like in picture above when user drag and
   drop control in application for example user put this control in container
   in application?
2. What code I need to allow user for drag and drop control?

You can give me example or link to tutorials and the I will try to write all code.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning question 1:

if you want to show such a property window in your application, you have to write it yourself and get all properties and their values using reflection.